# Prevent Disabled DAG from Running Instantly When Enabled

Tags: ubuntu, airflow-scheduler, airflow

In Airflow 1.10.10, when a disabled DAG is enabled by pressing the button to change it's state from `Off` to `On`, the DAG will always run once before the next scheduled run time.

[image]

Is it possible to set a DAG to be enabled, but not make its first run until the next time it is scheduled to be run?

Currently, I need to quickly kill the DAG run after I toggle its state to be `On`.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the start_date (which is a `datetime`) to value after `now`.

According to [the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html#to-keep-in-mind)

- the first DAG Run is created based on the minimum start_date for the
  tasks in your DAG.
- Subsequent DAG Runs are created by the scheduler
  process, based on your DAG’s schedule_interval, sequentially.

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically set the `start_date` to after `now` without [the problems associated with using dynamic `start_date` values](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date)? The goal is to not have to manually set `start_date` and still avoid having the DAG run instantly when it is enabled/resumed.

Comment: Yes, it can be a problem. I didn't think about it. You may need to set it somewhere externally, e.g. env var and read from the DAG

Answer (score 1):

If it is daily task - set start date as below : This will prevent your DAG from running immediately after enabling.

```
default_args = {
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1) 
}

If it is a monthly task - set start date as below :

default_args = {
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(30) 
}
```